# How to convert this unicode fraction(“¼” and “½”) to Number(1/2, 1/3) in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

**“¼” and “½”**, I just want to convert this Unicode fraction into the Number. I tried various methods and also searched google but I did not find any sollution.

If anyone has any idea how I can convert this Unicode fraction to the Number, it will be appriciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.prototype.normalize("NFKD")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to get the two operands from such characters:

```js
const unicodes = [ "¼","½","⅐","⅔","⅖","⅙","⅞" ];
unicodes.forEach((char) => {
  const normalized = char.normalize("NFKD");
  const operands = normalized.split("⁄");
  console.log( char, operands[0] + "/" + operands[1], operands[0] / operands[1] );
});
```

Comment: I think it's not working in this case "1¹⁄₂"

Comment: @GauravKumaru this is already normalized, so it doesn't count as an "unicode fraction". It's already three characters and you can already just split at the fraction sign (`⁄`). (and it actually still works, except if I miss what you are saying.)

Comment: Maybe `console.log( char, normalized, operands[0] / operands[1] );` could suffice (as there is no intent on evaluating this string) instead of `console.log( char, operands[0] + "/" + operands[1], operands[0] / operands[1] );`? BTW @GauravKumar evaluating `"1¹⁄₂"` or `"1½"` is a theme for another question…

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any context but it could be as simple as:

```
m = {'¼': 0.25, '½': 0.5 };
if(c in m) number = m[c];
```

Comment: it will be hard codded, right? what if we have some another Unicode value  other than this “¼” and “½” in fraction

Comment: I don't think you will have many in practice.  You could try @Kaiido's solution if that works better for you.