# How can I convert Unicode fractionals into ASCII fractionals in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

How can I convert something like "½" to "1/2" in pure C++ or Qt 6?

I saw an answer that hard coded a dictionary of specific Unicode strings, but how can I do it for every possible fractional instead of hard coding everything?

Comment: Somebody, somewhere, needs to maintain a list or a mapping of one to another. There is no single formula, or algorithm to perform this translation. The translation mapping is not going to pop out, all by itself, out of nowhere. A "hardcoded dictionary" is the only possible solution. If you don't hardcode it yoruself, use a library that contains this hardcoded mapping. The End.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66775632/how-to-convert-this-unicode-fraction-%c2%bc-and-%c2%bd-to-number1-2-1-3-in-js First answer here looks like a formula, but in JS

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Guess what? Unicode has such database. In the main Unicode database there is also the numeric value. How to use it, it is much more complex (some are positional, some additive, some mixed (like 1 3/4) and some also more complex. So probably an hard coded dictionary, just by finding "FRACTIONAL" in Unicode name, will be easier. (and as bonus, if we use the *correct* slash, many fonts will display numbers as expected in good fractional typography).

Answer (score 1):

```
void convertFractions(QString &input) {

    static QRegularExpression fractionRegex(QStringLiteral("[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]"));

    QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = fractionRegex.globalMatch(input);

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
        QString fraction = match.captured(0);

        fraction = fraction.normalized(QString::NormalizationForm_KD);

        input.replace(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), fraction);
    }
}
```

Textual representation from [Compart — List of Unicode Characters with Decomposition Mapping “Vulgar fraction form”](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/decomposition/%3Cfraction%3E):

| Unicode | Character |
| --- | --- |
| u00BC | ¼ |
| u00BE | ¾ |
| u2150 | ⅐ |
| u215E | ⅞ |